# requirejs Load timeout for config.js (optimized)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, amd

I have an optimized config.js (around 420kB) thats loaded by requirejs and everytime a new user registers and logs in this file is fetched and put in the cache , but the first time the user fetches this there is always a `Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: config`, and then the user has to refresh and then it loads.

I thought it's a timeout issue, so changed `waitSeconds : 200`. This happened in requireJs 2.1.6 so I upgraded to the latest 2.1.9 and still the same issue.

But if I don't use the optimizer and and use the unoptimized config file (3KB) which loads around 35-40 small js files (minified), it's going fine! But I want all the files to be in that optimized `config.js` because of less http requests (good for mobile).

Adding Code :

```
require.config({

    paths : {
        jquery        : './vendor/libs/jquery-1.10.1.min',
        underscore    : './vendor/libs/underscore-min',
        backbone      : './vendor/libs/backbone-min',
        marionette    : './vendor/libs/backbone.marionette',
        wreqr         : './vendor/plugins/backbone.wreqr.min',
        text          : './vendor/plugins/text',
        tpl           : './vendor/plugins/tpl',
        socketio      : '../socket.io/socket.io.min',
        spin          : './vendor/plugins/spin.min',
        shuffle       : './vendor/plugins/jquery.shuffleLetters',
        magicSuggest  : './vendor/plugins/magicsuggest-1.3.0-min',
        mCustomScroll : './vendor/plugins/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min',
        imagesloaded  : './vendor/plugins/imagesloaded',
        qTip          : './vendor/plugins/jquery.qtip.min',
        visibility    : './vendor/plugins/visibility',
        tab           : './vendor/plugins/tab',
        dropdown      : './vendor/plugins/dropdown',
        interestsMap  : './interestsMap',
        moment        : './vendor/plugins/moment.min',
        favicon       : './vendor/plugins/tinycon'

    },

    waitSeconds       : 180,

    shim : {

        socketio : {
            exports : 'io'
        },

        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        },

        backbone : {
            deps : ['underscore','jquery'],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        },

        marionette : {
            deps : ['backbone'],
            exports : 'Backbone.Marionette'
        },

        wreqr      : {
            deps : ['backbone'],
            exports : 'Backbone.Wreqr'
        },

        shuffle : {
            deps : ['jquery'],
            exports : 'jQuery.fn.shuffleLetters'
        },

        magicSuggest : {
            deps : ['jquery'],
            exports : 'jQuery.fn.magicSuggest'
        },

        mCustomScroll : {
            deps : ['jquery'],
            exports : 'jQuery.fn.mCustomScrollbar'
        },

        visibility : {
            exports : 'Visibility'
        },

        tab        : {
            deps : ['jquery'],
            exports : 'jQuery.fn.tab'
        },

        dropdown   : {
            deps : ['jquery'],
            exports : 'jQuery.fn.dropdown'
        },

        moment     : {
            exports : 'moment'
        },

        favicon    : {
            exports : 'Tinycon'
        }

    },

    tpl     : {
        extension : '.tpl'
    }
});

//Initialise 
require([
        'backbone',
        'routers/index',
        'app',
        ],function  (Backbone ,Router ,app){
            //var presence  = io.connect(w.protocol+'//'+w.host+'/presence');

            app.start();

            Backbone.history.start();


});
```

**There are no errors in any of the modules since there are loading fine with the unoptimised config.js file .

Build config

```
({
    appDir : '../',
    baseUrl: './scripts',
    dir    : '../../dist',
    mainConfigFile : '../scripts/config.js',
    name: "config",
    optimizeCss : 'standard'
})
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: updated with code : ). Right now im just doing this : requirejs.onError = function(check if type of error is timeout , if yes then reload() page ) . This works but bad UX

Comment: And your build config?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: hm, so your main script named as config, configuration also named as config plus you didnt mentioned out file. What about to try to rename modules in build file : `({
    appDir : '../',
    baseUrl: './scripts',
    dir    : '../../dist',
    mainConfigFile : '../scripts/config.js',
    name: "main", out: 'main-build.js'
    optimizeCss : 'standard'
})`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your problem you can disable the require js timeout with the require js config property waitSeconds (set to 0). Default timeout are 7 seconds (see more http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds).

But you should have a look at r.js (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject) because with this you can merge all your js source files into one bigger app.js file with all dependencies. To use it you should remove the dir property and add the out property in your config file.